# Can no longer press Windows key to launch Dash, what to do?

Tags: unity, 13.10, unity-dash

Suddenly pressing Windows key to launch Dash not working on my Ubuntu 13.10, other shortcut works fine (Windows + 1, Windows + T, Windows hold), I have tried to restart my computer but the problem persist. On 13.04 I can easily fix unity-related problem using unity --reset, but I just tried it and now --reset is deprecated? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it. I have to reset unity using `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` then `setsid unity`. I have tried to reproduce the problem, and it's happening again after I changed Launcher Opacity in CCSM, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Open CompizConfig Settings Manager -> Ubuntu Unity Plugin. Choose the Launcher tab. There you can change the setting to Super under Key to show Dash,Launcher and Help overlay. That's it! [image]

Comment: This is my CCSM configuration,https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75813759/CCSM.png, still no luck